# .htaccess redirect leading zeros URL to clean URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Let's say I have URLs like these (with leading zeros before the number):

```
http://example.com/directory/page/0023/
http://example.com/directory/page/01/
```

How can I redirect them to a URL without the leading zeros? For example:

```
http://example.com/directory/page/23/
http://example.com/directory/page/1/
```

I've used this snippet of code in my .htaccess file to manage redirects with my site of this nature:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+directory/(?:page|)/1/
RewriteRule ^ /directory/? [L,R=301]
```

If there's any way that this snippet of code can be altered to work with my issue (which I'm stuck on how to do), it would be great.

Comment: `RewriteRule directory/page/0+(\d+)/?$ directory/page/$1/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/directory/page/0+([0-9]+)/ /directory/page/$1
```

Though, if that interferes with the rule you currently have, you can also convert that to use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /directory/(?:page|)/1/ /directory/
```

Or use mod_rewrite for both:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+directory/page/0+([0-9]+)/
RewriteRule ^ /directory/page/%1/[L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+directory/(?:page|)/1/
RewriteRule ^ /directory/? [L,R=301]
```